# How to use JWT and 0auth together

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, architecture, jwt

I'm trying to build a application based on RESTful API and I'd like to provide a method for authentication both JWT and 0auth (JWT for user access and 0auth for app access).
In short I'd like to do:

```
User Access (Web App, Mobile App - JWT)
------------------------> /
                            ----------------------->  /api/login
                            ----------------------->  /api/logout

Client's app (API KEY - 0auth)
------------------------> /services/getInfo
                          /services/getProducts
```

A user can use the web application and could wish to integrate some functionality of its app with my services, like Facebook, Github and so on..

I ain't sure about this approach because it's the first time I design a big application.
The questions are as follows:

1. Should I also use JWT for authentication by app?
2. Using JWT, can I trace how many request the apps do?
3. Can I revoke a JWT token?
4. Is 0auth protocol better than JWT for authentication by app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oauth 2.0 is an authorization protocol and it shouldn't be used for authentication. Consider using Openid Connect for your scenario. It works on top of oauth so the flow would be identical with some improvisations for authentication.

In this case, you can register your application to use the same protocol for both end users as well as for calls within your applications.

Please explore client credentials flow for app access and implicit/hybrid flow for Web App.

Openid connect uses jwt tokens for authentication and authorization.

Identity server 3 is a certified implementation of Openid connect. Their documentation is good and they have an active support forum to help you with queries.

Please Refer :

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/identity-and-data/9781491937006/ch04.html

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/01/17/which-openid-connectoauth-2-o-flow-is-the-right-one/

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples